# Oracle 11 Visual Studio 2015 odp.net connection failure

Tags: visual-studio, oracle11g, visual-studio-2015

I cannot use oracle.dataaccess.dll 4.112.3.0 on visual studio 2015.

First of all, installed visual studio 2015 pro then, installed oracle 11.2.3.0 but visual studio is not able to see oracle.dataaccess.dll in the assembly reference list to add. When I add the dll from the Oracle home odp.net bin 4 directory, I can only compile the project. On the run time, it fails and cannot connect. It returns exception saying 'the provider is not compatible with the client.'.

Comment: Have you installed ODP.net (Oracle Data Provider for Dot net) ? Check this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: Yes I installed as I stated but it did not work.